# How many ways are there to select an ordered pair of numbers from $1$ to $7$ so that the sum is even?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to select an ordered pair of numbers from $1$ to $7$ so that the sum is even?

Soln: The way I tried approaching this problem was, I made a grid of $7 \times 7$ squares. So $49$ ordered pairs in total.  Also the sum of two numbers is even only if the numbers selected are either both even or both odd. So, how do I proceed further?
Thank you.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig: May as well fix that "Soln" :)

Comment: @barakmanos  My motivation for editing was that the title was not specific to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are allowed to select each element **once**, then add up the following:

- The number of ways to select an ordered pair from $\{2,4,6\}$, which is $3\cdot2=6$
- The number of ways to select an ordered pair from $\{1,3,5,7\}$, which is $4\cdot3=12$

---

If we are allowed to select each element **twice**, then add up the following:

- The number of ways to select an ordered pair from $\{2,4,6\}$, which is $3\cdot3=9$
- The number of ways to select an ordered pair from $\{1,3,5,7\}$, which is $4\cdot4=16$

Comment: Your solution is correct if the members of the ordered pair must be different.  If we permit both members of the ordered pair to be equal, there are an additional seven solutions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: You are correct! I will edit the answer. Thank you for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 2):

Your table is

$\begin{array}[ht]{|p{2cm}|||p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}  \hline \text{sum }  & 1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 & 7\\ \hline \hline \hline 1 &\color{red}2 &3 &\color{red}4 &5 &\color{red}6 &7&\color{red}8 \\  \hline 2 & 3 &\color{red}4 &5 &\color{red}6 &7&\color{red}8 &9 \\ \hline 3&\color{red}4 &5 &\color{red}6 &7 &\color{red}8&9&\color{red}{10} \\ \hline 4 &5 &\color{red}6 &7&\color{red}8&9&\color{red}{10}&11  \\ \hline  5 &\color{red}6 &7&\color{red}8&9&\color{red}{10}&11&\color{red}{12}  \\ \hline 6 &7&\color{red}8&9&\color{red}{10}&11&\color{red}{12}&13 \\ \hline  7&\color{red}8&9&\color{red}{10}&11&\color{red}{12}&13&\color{red}{14}  \\ \hline \end{array}$

The red marked numbers are the even sums. Now you can sum up the up-right diagonals of the red marked numbers: $1+3+5+7+5+3+1=25$

Additional you can calculate the probability of selecting an even sum.

The number of possible outcomes is $7\cdot 7=49$

Therefore the probability to select an ordered pair of numbers from 
1 to 7 so that the sum is even is $\frac{25}{49}\approx 51\%$

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it ask to compute the probability.

Comment: Yes, Í´ll edit it.